# Failed to load ios simulator in Xamarin Studio on Mac

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I try to run first welcome ios app on Xamarin Studio using Xamarin.Forms app,
But when I try to run in debug mode, simulator not running and give this message in Application Output without errors:

> Failed to launch the simulator: Attempting to register a class named: DTDKRemoteDeviceToken which is a valid protocol
>   error MT1008: Failed to launch the simulator: Attempting to register a class named: DTDKRemoteDeviceToken which is a valid protocol.

Note: That this application created in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.
I tried to run app with connecting VS to Mac Agent but connection never success, (Maybe another problem that I will talk about), When all steps fails to connect I copied application to Mac OSX Siera and try to run it, but it fails :(

Any help, please.

Comment: Add `-v -v -v -v` in the `Xamarin.iOS` "**Additional mtouch arguments**" field, delete the obj/bin directories and perform a Rebuild/Debug cycle and post the full error from log

Comment: Can you explain where i set -v -v -v -v in the project

Comment: @EslamNano You can find **Additional mtouch arguments** on the iOS Build Options (right click on the iOS Project --> Properties --> iOS Build). Check out the bottom of this image https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/Images/Linking02W.png

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like there may be an issue with your remote iOS simulator (an simulator that runs on your windows pc, by connecting to your mac). What I would recommend doing, is disabling this feature in:

Tools > Options > Xamarin > iOS settings

And uncheck “Remote Simulator to Windows”.

This will launch the simulator on your mac using XCode.